# Does Oracle Apex support table partitioning?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm new to Oracle and Apex, and I'm building a table that will potentially become very large over time.

It would be ideal to partition by date range, and then subpartition by hash.

Does Apex support table partitioning?
Googling yielded no results, which makes me think it's unsupported.
(All I could find was Oracle DB articles, not Apex.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apex is just an application layer on top of your Oracle database. It does not know about how a table is organised. I have many applications using partitioned tables, this is not an issue.

Comment: The question will be in licencing. On premise, this used to be a costed option. In the cloud, you may find this is included.